# How to change max in each row to 1, all other numbers to 0 in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In tensorflow I am trying to replace the maximum value in each row of a 2D array with 1 and all other numbers with zero like this;

```
x = tf.constant(
    [[0, 4],
     [2,3],
     [6,7],
     [9,2]]) 
output should be like this;
[[0, 1],
     [0,1],
     [0,1],
     [1,0]])
```

So far I have been able to turn the maximum value to 1 and all the other values to zero by using following code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.constant(
    [[0, 4],
     [2,3],
     [6,7],
     [9,2]])

top_values, top_indices = tf.nn.top_k(tf.reshape(x, (-1,)), 1)
output = tf.cast(tf.greater_equal(x, top_values), tf.float64)
Output: ([[0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]
 [1. 0.]])
```

But how I can get the max value=1 in each array separately. Can someone help me how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of reshaping `x` you can do it in a vectorized way as follows:

```py
top_vals, _ = tf.nn.top_k(x, 1)
output = tf.cast(tf.greater_equal(x, top_vals), tf.float64)
output
```

Output:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 2), dtype=float64, numpy=
array([[0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [1., 0.]])>
```